# Is the strict inductive limit complemented in the direct sum?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a strict (LB)-space, i.e. the locally convex inductive limit of a strict inductive sequence of Banach spaces $X_n$. Then $X$ is linearly homeomorphic to a quotient $(\bigoplus_n X_n) / F$ by a closed subspace $F$ of the locally convex direct sum $\bigoplus_n X_n$. Is $F$ a complemented subspace?

A sufficient condition would be that $F$ has countable codimension. (In a barrelled space any algebraic complement of a countably codimensional subspace is topological, see [Wilansky, "Modern Methods in Topological Vector Spaces", Theorem 13-3-19]).

If this is not true, are there any other known simple conditions on the strict inductive sequence such that $F$ is complemented?

Comment: If $F$ has countable codimension then $X$ is the inductive limit of finite dimensional spaces which is a very special situation. One could look at LB-spaces of *Moscatelli type* which were thoroughly investigated by Bonet and Dierolf for a counterexample.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for the hint. Let $X$ be a Banach space which is not a Hilbert space and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$ which is not complemented (these exist by the famous theorem of Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri), e.g. $X = l^\infty$ and $Y = c_0$. Take a normal Banach sequence space $\lambda$ (e.g. $\lambda = l^2$) and define the $\lambda$-direct sum Banach space $F_n := (X^n \oplus \bigoplus_{k \in \mathbb{N}} Y)_\lambda$. The inclusion maps turn $F_n$ into a strict inductive sequence. Denote by $F$ the corresponding strict (LB)-space. Then $F$ is not complemented in $\bigoplus F_n$. ...

Comment: ... $F$ is an example of a "standard twisted (LB)-space". In fact, $F$ is not complemented in any countable direct sum of locally convex spaces each having a total bounded set. This is due to [Metafune, Moscatelli, "On twisted Fréchet spaces and (LB)-spaces" (1990), Theorem 1.5(a)].